# When using two linked JSON files, how do I use variable from outter within the one inside?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a loop within $.getJSON double functions.
This one works:

```
$.getJSON('data/lige.json',
function (lige) {
  $.getJSON('data/ponude.json',
  function (ponude) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ponude.length; i++) {
      console.log('test');
    }
  });
});
```

However this doesn't work:

```
$.getJSON('data/lige.json',
function (lige) {
  $.getJSON('data/ponude.json',
  function (ponude) {
    for (var i = 0; i < lige.length; i++) {
      console.log('test');
    }
  });
});
```

And this returns: `Object { lige: Array[3] }`

```
$.getJSON('data/lige.json',
function (lige) {
  $.getJSON('data/ponude.json',
  function (ponude) {
    console.log(lige);
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried a.lige.length?

Comment: If it shows up in the console what makes you think it doesn't see it?

Comment: @Oliver my bad, that log was from another code, now I fixed it.

Comment: @Alvaro Because the loop does not even start, and that I just a guess. I do not understand why loop doesn't start.

Comment: Can you please edit the question once more and post the real code? I'd assume that `console.log('test')` would print `test`, not `Object { lige: Array[3] }`.

Comment: @Avaro The third code block, to be more precise the part console.log(lige) returns  Object {lige: Array[3] } the second code block should return one or more 'test' strings inside console

Comment: I guess the problem is that you're trying to get the length of an object. What does lige.json look like?

Comment: @Oliver I found the problem. The problem was within targeting. I targeted an array that has array inside of it. for (var i=0; i < lige.lige.length; i++) was the right targeting way. Thank you guys for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `lige` object has a property called `lige` inside it which is the array you want.

Try

```
for (var i = 0; i < lige.lige.length; i++) {
  console.log('test');
}
```